# PIC Clock frequency change by registers and edit project window

Tags: frequency, clock, pic

I am trying to set MCU clock frequency but I got confused. When I set it by registers (By coding) it seems like it does not change it. But when I change it from "edit project" window it starts to work. So my questions are:

1. What is the difference between changing MCU Clock by registers and from "edit project" window? Do I need to change both of them? What happens when they are 2 different frequencies?
2. Is there a difference betweeen oscillator frequency and MCU Clock frequency?
3. If I need to have 1 mHz clock frequency do I need to set MCU Clock to 1 mHz or to 4 mHz? Because in some websites they say that 1 operation take 4 clock cycles in PIC.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which PIC but in modern ones you can change clock frequency in several places. One is configuration bits and this is what can be set in "edit project". Config.bits set the clock source (external,internal) as well as PLL. Another place is registers (`OSCCON1` and friends), where you can switch between clock sources. There is also a config bit that allows/disallows clock switching.
The easiest way to make sense of all that is to install Microchip Code Configurator plugin into MplabX and set your clock/peripherals there. It will output chip-specific C code which you can then use in your project.